# Using typeof on props results in TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am passing a message when I redirect to login component which is then passed to Loginform  as prop

Login.js

```
class Login extends React.Component {
constructor(props) { super(props);}
render() {
 let msg = "";
 console.log(typeof this.props.location.state); // Always exists
 console.log(typeof this.props.location.state.redirectmsg); // results in typeError
 if(typeof this.props.location.state.redirectmsg!=='undefined') { // results in TypeError
   msg=this.props.location.state.redirectmsg;
 }
 return <Loginform msg={msg} />;
 }
}
```

Redirect

```
 const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
<Route {...rest} render={props => (false === true ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { redirectmsg: "Kindly login first"} }} />)} />);
```

But when I try to check if its undefined or not it gives me error.Even console.log gives me error.

Answer : Since state key itself is undefined at first

```
   let msg = ((this.props.location || {}).state || {}).redirectmsg || "";
   return <Loginform msg={msg} />;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key

Comment: @Teemu I don't need to check nested keys as this.props.location.state always exists as shown.

Comment: is this.props.location.state undefined? if that is the case you are trying to access to a property (redirectmsg) of something undefined that will lead to an error. If that is the case I recommend you to check lodash _.get, you can call it in this way _.get(this, 'props.location.state.redirectmsg', default_value_if_something_is_undef), that will avoid to check if this is undef, if prof is undef if location is undef if state is undef, etc.

Comment: @charlieme this.props.location.state always exists

Comment: please mention how do you pass the redirectmsg to the login component.Seems like redirectmsg is not there in this.props.location.state

Comment: @Harikrishnan Already mentioned in redirect code

Comment: yes, it exists and it has a value, but the first time it doesn't have a value, check my answer and verify the log appending a +'' in order to break the reference.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @Vibhas Your question was about the type error, not about showing a message (that is what I answered).

Answer (score 3):

this.props.location.state is being logged in the console with a value because it's referencing to the latest value, so at the beginning it's 'undefined' and then it is updated with another value.

Try replacing

```
console.log(typeof this.props.location.state);
```

with

```
console.log(typeof this.props.location.state + '');
```

And check if it's undefined or not (I guess it will be undefined this time).

Converting it to a string will break the reference, and you will see it was undefined (the first value of the typeof this.props.location.state).

At that point you was calling this.props.location.state.redirectmsg and that will generate a type error because this.props.location.state was undefined.

For this kind of validation I recommend you to use lodash or underscore _.get (using that get, you can check for deep properties and use a default value if some of the properties are undefined).

Example using lodash get:

```
let msg = _.get(this, 'props.location.state.redirectmsg', '');
```

Comment: this is not going to fix the error, I asked you to make this change in order to verify this sentence:  console.log(typeof this.props.location.state+''); // Always exists, after appending '', it exists or it's undefined?

Comment: if console.log(typeof this.props.location.state+'') (with the appended string) is logging undefined that is because at the begining that value es undefined, and then (some miliseconds later) the parent component of the login is updating the props of the login (for that reason you are seeing a value when the string is not appended).

Comment: yes your are right.so state itself is undefined first that's why accessing redirectmsg gives error.

Comment: You can solve it by rendering the Login component in the parent component only if you have that location.state, or you can validate inside of your login that the state and location are not undefined

Comment: Instead of those manual validations I recommend you to check lodash _.get https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get  This is a lot nicer: let msg = _.get(this, 'props.location.state.redirectmsg', '');

Answer (score -1):

try `undefined` without the single quotes

```
class Login extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
render() {
    let msg = "";
    console.log(typeof this.props.location.state); // Ok
    console.log(typeof this.props.location.state.redirectmsg);
    if (typeof this.props.location.state.redirectmsg !== undefined) {
        msg = this.props.location.state.redirectmsg;
    }
    return <Loginform msg = {
        msg
    }
    />;
}
}
```

Comment: Already tried didn't work.Also console.log() line before that gives error first

Comment: @JamilAmini `typeof yourVariable` always returns a `string`. So, your solution is wrong when u are comparing with `===` because it compares strictly, both type and values.